# What is the complexity of s[::-1] where `s` is a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, time-complexity, space-complexity

Can you explain both in terms of time and space.
This question here explains slicing in python very well but falls short in terms of detailed complexity analysis. - [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Linear for both

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend on the implementation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, can you explain a bit of under the hood, thanks once again

Comment: @DYZ suppose I am just assigning `s = "lol" and then printing `print(s[::-1])`